# f2py error wrong elsize

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, elf, f2py

- OS Ubuntu 14.04 on 64-bit notebook
- I compile a function written in the Fortran code using f2py
- then I call this function from Python.

And I get error message:
ValueError: failed to initialize intent(inout) array -- expected elsize=4 but got 8

It looks like my Fortran code is being compiled as a 32-bit in spite of 64-bit machine.
On 32-bit computer everything works fine.
What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I have found solution.
First, reported error raises only when integer arrays are being passed to Fortran subroutine. Integer values and real arrays (I suppose, values too) pass correctly, when I use default Python int and float, while in Fortran I declare them as INTEGER*4 and REAL*8.
But in the case of integer arrays this did not work. Minor corrections needed, namely, integer arrays in Python should be declared as (or converted to) np.int32 type and declared as INTEGER*4 in Fortran subroutine.
Here are samples of array declaration/conversion that worked in my project.

Python:

```
import numpy as np
import Fortran_file
#.... some code
# variable "data" is integer 2-D array
data = data.astype(np.int32) # data.astype(int) gives error
data =  np.asfortranarray(data)
array1 = np.zeros(5, dtype=np.int32, order='F') # dtype=int gives error
array2 = np.zeros(5, dtype=float, order='F')
ivalue = 2 # conversion to np.int32 is not needed
Fortran_file.Fortran_subroutine(data, ivalue, array1, array2)
```

Fortran:

```
SUBROUTINE Fortran_subroutine (matrix, value, array1, array2)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER*4 :: matrix(:,:)
!f2py  INTENT(INOUT) :: matrix(:,:)
INTEGER*4 :: value
!f2py  INTENT(INOUT) :: value
INTEGER*4 :: array1(5)
!f2py INTENT(INOUT):: array1(5)
REAL*8 :: array2(5)
!f2py INTENT(INOUT) :: array2(5)
```

Again, this had sense on 64-bit OS. When I used 32-bit OS, everything worked without these tricks.

I have not experimented with other data types.